# https not working in Linux with node/express/webpack

Tags: node.js, linux, express, webpack-4

I have a nodejs application, I am able to configure https and run it locally on my windows machin, but when I do the same run on my Linux machin it fails with below error.

> EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3006

```
events.js:282
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3006
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1308:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1356:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1495:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1335:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3006
}
```

As suggested by other I tried 'netstat -plnt' but the port **3006** is nowhere used, so nothing to kill.

Not sure if this is code issue or OS issue.
[Update] chnaged the port to 3006

```
netstat -plnt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: what Linux machine are you using ubuntu, rhel etc ??

Comment: @Taj its AWS's EC2 default Linux AMI (ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora")

Comment: sudo netstat -anp | grep :3006

Comment: Are you trying to run a Node app with https.createServer? Are you trying to run certbot on the web app? What is your engine at the moment? NGINX?

Comment: @MattiaRasulo yes by https.createServer, I am using express.js as app server.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `fuser 1223/tcp` to get the process and 
           `fuser -k 1223/tcp` to kill the process running on the specific port

Comment: netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':1223' ? If this doesn't work can you please try running your application? or run the port commands as a sudo user?

Comment: I switched to 3006 port, but after this command ' sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':3006'' it returns blank..no output just next command line..